# Getting error while encoding str in UTF8 format

Tags: string, python-2.7, python-3.x

> This is working code.

```
line = 'line'
another_line = 'new ' + line
another_line.encode('utf-8')
```

> output

```
b'new line'
```

Now I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting the error for below code in python3 vs I'm getting concatenated string in python2 ?.

```
line = 'line'
'new '+line.encode('utf-8')
```

> TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states, Python3 will not automatically convert a byte type to a string (the `+` operator sees a string first so wants a string on the right as well) implicitly (automatically) so you need to tell it explicitly to do so.

```
line = 'line'
print('new '+str(line.encode('utf-8')))
```

note that this gives slightly different output.

If you want the exact same output then this works:

```
line = 'line'
print('new '.encode('utf-8')+line.encode('utf-8'))
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html)

"The + (addition) operator yields the sum of its arguments. The arguments must either both be numbers or both be sequences of the same type. In the former case, the numbers are converted to a common type and then added together. In the latter case, the sequences are concatenated." and "Python evaluates expressions from left to right. Notice that while evaluating an assignment, the right-hand side is evaluated before the left-hand side."